# Multipart content type response parsing

Tags: c#, multipart, dotnet-httpclient

Response from server to client is sent in multipart format. Server response formatter class:

```
class MyMultipartFromatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{
    ...
    public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
    {
       ...
       var multipartFormData = new MultipartFormDataContent("----abc123");
       content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "boundary=----abc123");
       ... // Adding data
       multipartFormData.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result.CopyTo(writeStream);
    }
}
```

Parsing response in client side:

```
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
var multipart = response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result;
```

ReadAsMultipartAsync throws this exception:

```
{"Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content-type header value. 'HttpContent' instances must have a content-type header starting with 'multipart/'.\r\nParameter name: content"}
```

I guess problem is that response.Content has no response header where is content type and boundary is set. How to format/parse multipart response correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting valid content-type ('multipart/form-data') here - `content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "boundary=----abc123");`

Comment: I mean, `"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----abc123"`

Comment: That would make: "multipart/form-data; multipart/form-data; boundary=----abc123"